# Помогите сконфигурировать nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

есть конфигурационный файл nginx:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   C:\Users\comp\www;
        index  index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html; 
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/$1;
    }

    #location = /admin/addProductType {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/addProductType;
    #}
    #        location = /admin/getListProductType {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/getListProductType;
    #}
}
}
```

Как можно настроить nginx чтобы не прописывать каждый раз location с proxy_pass вроде:

```
    location = /admin/addProductType {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/addProductType;
    }
    location = /admin/getListProductType {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/getListProductType;
    }
```

А сделать чтобы он автоматически перенаправлял запросы с localhost/admin/* на http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/*?

Делал rewrite ^/admin/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/$1 permanent;, но при этом когда заходишь на localhost/admin/getListProductType браузер перекидывает на http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/getListProductType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/;
}
```

http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> Если директива `proxy_pass` указана с URI, то при передаче запроса серверу часть *нормализованного* URI запроса, соответствующая `location`, заменяется на URI, указанный в директиве

Comment: Почему-то запрос перенаправляется только с localhost/admin/addProductType на 127.0.0.1:8080/admin/addProductType, а на остальные выдает ошибку 404. И как сделать чтобы в браузере "127.0.0.1:8080/admin/a" отражался как "localhost/admin/a"? Иначе Chrome блокирует запрос CORS политикой.